# Try refresh token and invalidate query when react-query encounters 401

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-query

I would like to create a wrapper hook around react-query's `useQuery` hook so that I could catch a 401 error, attempt to refresh access token and if successfully refreshed - invalidate the original query.

Full example of what I am trying to do is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-booth-hbe12?file=/src/App.js

```js
function useMyQUery() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { tryRefreshToken } = useSession();

  const query = useQuery(...arguments);

  if (query.isError && query.error?.status === 401) {
    tryRefreshToken().then((tokenRefreshSucccessful) =>
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("todos")
    );
  } else {
    return query;
  }

  return {};
}
```

In the example I have linked above I am able to catch the error, trigger the function `tryRefetchToken`, but the functions inside the `useSession` hook do not seem to pick up the token once it is set.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can trigger side-effects like `tryRefreshToken()` or `queryClient.invalidateQueries` directly in the render function. Try putting these side-effects into the `onError` callback of `useQuery`, or in a `useEffect`. Something like:

```
function useMyQUery() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const { tryRefreshToken } = useSession()

  return useQuery(key, fn, {
    onError: (error) => {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        tryRefreshToken().then((tokenRefreshSucccessful) =>
          queryClient.invalidateQueries("todos")
        )
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path, however `onError` does not suppress the error from being exposed to the consumer, but what works is `retry` option, which accepts a callback function (retryCount, error) => ... , which works as expected and does not expose the error to the consumer unless you return `false` from that callback. Now the final issue that I have is that queryFn which is set up in the useSession context should read a state value `token` from that context, but it never gets the updated value, just the initial one.

Comment: if you want to hide the error completely, I would do the refresh directly in the `queryFn`

Comment: I would like to keep that uncoupled from the query function and I don't want it it to disappear completely, just swallow the 401 the first time.

Comment: How would you suggest to deal with mutation <its rare but is there an easy way / approach to do it>